# How to use PHP preg_replace and Javascript to replace 'link format' with a link tag

Tags: php, javascript, html, hyperlink, preg-replace

I want to allow links in a blog comments field but only if they are written in the following format (like reddit):

```
[reddit!](http://reddit.com)
```

And I want to turn them into a real link with PHP and with JavaScript:

```
<a href="http://reddit.com">reddit!</a>
```

I will use the JavaScript conversion to show a live preview on the page and the PHP conversion as server-side validation.

I don't need to add a `rel="nofollow"` to the link but I will need to add a `http://` if one is omitted.

I know lots of websites allow for this kind of linking (like Stackoverflow) so aret there any code samples available anywhere?

Comment: Hey, I know that face! :) Some of your css layout examples have been very helpful for me at times. So a heartfelt thank you from me!

Comment: Hey thanks @fireeyedboy! You're more than welcome ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You effectively want a PHP [markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) parser: http://michelf.com/projects/php-markdown/

Here is a different project with a code example of how to parse the syntax you requested: https://github.com/wolfie/php-markdown/blob/extra/markdown.php#L678